# Postgres Error when creating a new table using migration command

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I am trying to set up a nodeJs project in my system. This project has different database environment for local and development, for which the username, password and other credentials are added in knex.js

I have installed Postgres, in my local (and used the same username and password as that of my system)

I need to create a new table, for that I ran this command to create the migration file

`knex migrate:make 'test' --env local --knexfile db/knex.js`

A file is created. Then in this file I added the code to create the table

```
exports.up = function (knex, Promise) {
    return knex.schema
        .createTable('oxygen', table => {
            table.increments('id').primary();
            table.string('name').notNull();
        });
};

exports.down = function (knex, Promise) {
    return knex.schema.dropTable('oxygen');
};
```

Now in order to create table in the database, I ran this migration command

```
knex migrate:latest --env local --knexfile db/knex.js
```

But I am getting this error

```
Working directory changed to ~/backend/db
Using environment: local
password authentication failed for user "postgres"
error: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
    at Connection.parseE (/home/bhavya/backend/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:614:13)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/home/bhavya/backend/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:413:19)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/bhavya/backend/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:129:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:212:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23)
```

The knex.js file includes following part of code for connecting with the local db

```
local: {
        client: 'pg',
        useNullAsDefault: true,
        migrations: {
            directory: './../db/migrations'
        },
        seeds: {
            directory: './../db/seeds'
        },
        connection: {
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            user: 'postgres',
            password: 'postgres',
            database: 'backend'
        }
    },
```

Comment: `error: password authentication failed for user "postgres"` is pretty plainly telling you that your credentials for connecting to the database are wrong...

Comment: @AKX yes, but I have rechecked the password credentials and they are correct. And then how `knex migrate:make 'test' --env local --knexfile db/knex.js` this command ran successfully ?

Comment: Maybe it didn't connect to the database to just create a new migration file?

Comment: @AKX I am using ubuntu and have set up a new user password. Is there any command which I can run to connect to Postgres locally in authenticated mode, so that I can verify if the user password I am using in knex.js is correct ?

Comment: It looks like Knex is trying to connect using the username `postgres`. What exactly do you have in your knexfile?

Comment: @AKX I have added the part of knex.js file in the question above, can you please look into this ?

Comment: Your knex file is attempting to connect using the username `postgres` and the password `postgres`. Do you have such credentials set up in your PostgreSQL configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@escoder, Use the below command to login locally into PostgreSQL by using username and password via Ubuntu terminal

`psql postgresql://<username>:<password>@localhost:5432`

Then, If you face this below error in your terminal

`FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"`

you have to reset your password of **postgres** user.